# How do I install Pterodacty local on my maschine

Tags: windows, panel, local

I am attempting to install the Pterodactyl Panel on my local machine for development designing purposes. I am running Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: There's no question here.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pterodactyl installation documentation page](https://pterodactyl.io/panel/1.0/getting_started.html#picking-a-server-os), Here are some OS that can run Pterodactyl:

- Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 22.04
- CentOS 7, 8
- Debian 10, 11

And the way of installation is also mostly using the linux command. From here it can be concluded, **maybe Pterodactyl can not be installed / running on Windows**.

Try to use something like a vps or linux vm to run Pterodactyl, if it's just for development don't need to use too high specs.

> Source: https://pterodactyl.io/panel/1.0/getting_started.html#picking-a-server-os